# Unable to export Android Studio Code Inspection report

Tags: html, android-studio, export, intellij-inspections

when I try to export the report from ***Analyze -> Inspect Code***, the report is not saved and the event log show the following error from IDE Fatal Error window:

[image]

> null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.DescriptorComposer.composeDescription(DescriptorComposer.java:195)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.ex.DescriptorComposer.compose(DescriptorComposer.java:64)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.lambda$null$0(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:107)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.traverseInspectionTree(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:63)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.traverseInspectionTree(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:65)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.traverseInspectionTree(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:65)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.traverseInspectionTree(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:65)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.lambda$serializeTreeToHtml$2(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:84)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.appendTree(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:185)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.serializeTreeToHtml(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:72)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.export.InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.(InspectionTreeHtmlWriter.java:54)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.ui.actions.ExportHTMLAction.lambda$null$0(ExportHTMLAction.java:102)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:912)
>       at com.intellij.codeInspection.ui.actions.ExportHTMLAction.lambda$null$1(ExportHTMLAction.java:96)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:247)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:397)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:575)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I tried to run Android Studio as admin, no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating gradle build file and Android Studio version.